# html after before tags not work correct

Tags: html, css

I have navigation div, there are buttons for example only img not links, I want before ant after this images add lines:
 I try :

```
#nav{                   
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0;}

#nav ul li img{
    padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

html:

```
<li><img src="./img/dot.gif" alt=""/></li>
```

I add to css this codes to add after and bofore images lines:

```
#nav ul li img:before{
  background: url('./img/orange-pixel.gif') repeat-x 50% 50%; 
  width: 40px; 
  height: 3px; 
  float: left; 
  padding-top: 45px;} 
#nav ul li img:after{
  background: url('./img/orange-pixel.gif') repeat-x 50% 50%; 
  width: 40px; 
  height: 3px; 
  float: left; 
  padding-top: 45px;}
```

But doesn't display lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://lildude.co.uk/after-css-property-for-img-tag) post, most browsers doesn't compute `:before`/`:after` for `img` tags. To help you anyway: Why don't you set lines by adding a border to the images. Or use `:before`/`:after` on the `li` tag?

Comment: in `li` tags I also have link, but ok I add class to li img and try

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
content:".";
text-indent:-9999em;
display:block
```

to your :before & :after. All this does is gives it something to "grab onto" and it should work.

If they're basic lines though, why not just add a border to one side of the li? :before and :after don't work in legacy browsers, so it's a more consistent experience if they're necessary.